# How to assign values to the array

Tags: java, arrays

I am taking input and I want it to print out all the numbers in the array but for some reason the array only saves the last number inputted. Also the code should stop when null is entered and one number per line
My input:

```
1
2 3
4
<enter>
```

My output:

```
[4]
```

My expected output:

```
 [1,2,3,4]
```

The program

```
String inputValue; 
String [] input = new String[500];

while((inputValue = stdin.readLine()) != null && !inputValue.equals("")){
    input = inputValue.split("\\s+");         
} 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));
```

Comment: On every line you read you reassign the input array to a new value.

Comment: So how do I fix that

Comment: I gonna update ma answer

Answer (score 0):

possible mistake is that you assigned`input = inputValue.split("\\s+");` in every iteration of loop. It caused that you will see only last line or last character

```
String inputValue; 
inputCount=0;
String [] input = new String[500];

while((inputValue = stdin.readLine()) != null && !inputValue.equals("")){
    String [] inputLine = inputValue.split("\\s+");  
    for(i =0; i<inputLine.length; i++){
       input[inputCount++] = inputLine[i];
    }
}
input = Arrays.copyOf(input, inputCount);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));
```

Try this. It is olny possible misstake

Comment: Everytime I enter a number it throw an outofbounds error

Comment: do you know line? where

Comment: Well I just had to delete the equal sign and now though it adds a bunch of nulls to my array

Comment: You need to truncate the Array at the end (copy it to a shorter one) or only use the first inputCount elements. `input = Arrays.copyOf(input, inputCount);`

Comment: @swaguire, it doesn't add nulls, this nulls are in array immediately after declaration in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect the values over multile loop invocations. You can do it like this:

```
ArrayList<String> inputList = new ArrayList<>();
String line;
while((line = stdin.readLine()) != null
       && !line.equals(""))
{
    String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
    inputList.addAll(Arrays.asList(words));         
} 
System.out.println(inputList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        String inputValue = ""; 
        String [] input = new String[500];
        int count = 0;

            for(int i = 0 ; i < input.length; i++){
                System.out.println("Enter Value : ");
                inputValue = s.nextLine();
                input[i] = inputValue;
                count ++;

                if(inputValue.trim().isEmpty())
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

        String[] tmpArray = new String[count-1];

        count = 0;

        for(String number : input)
        {
            if(number != null && !number.trim().isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(number);
                tmpArray[count] = number;
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmpArray));

    }
}
```

Tried this and everything works good! I also added the trim() function so to make sure that you remove all trailing spaces.